# Looping through list, where each cell is a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a Pandas dataframe, and I called Google Maps API on each address cell to get more location-based data using apply

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3


geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key='AIzaSyBlNIvZTk-BpWDeX1FFXPbx6QwbNzZL80w', timeout=5)
location1 = test_df['address_original'].apply(geolocator.geocode)
location2 = location1.apply(lambda loc: loc.raw if loc else None)

print location2

0     {u'geometry': {u'location_type': u'ROOFTOP', u...
1     {u'geometry': {u'location': {u'lat': 51.217491...
2     {u'geometry': {u'location': {u'lat': 51.308421...
3     {u'geometry': {u'location_type': u'APPROXIMATE...
4     {u'geometry': {u'location_type': u'GEOMETRIC_C...
5     {u'geometry': {u'location': {u'lat': 51.587061...
6     {u'geometry': {u'location_type': u'GEOMETRIC_C...
7     {u'geometry': {u'location': {u'lat': 50.901207...
8     {u'geometry': {u'location': {u'lat': 51.647805...
9     {u'geometry': {u'location': {u'lat': 50.640587...
10    {u'geometry': {u'location': {u'lat': 50.651339...
```

The return in each cell is a dictionary object

```
print location2[0]

{u'geometry': {u'location_type': u'ROOFTOP', u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': 52.11653860000001, u'lng': -106.6477325}, u'southwest': {u'lat': 52.1164591, u'lng': -106.6478363}}, u'viewport': {u'northeast': {u'lat': 52.1178478302915, u'lng': -106.6464354197085}, u'southwest': {u'lat': 52.1151498697085, u'lng': -106.6491333802915}}, u'location': {u'lat': 52.1165023, u'lng': -106.6477809}}, u'address_components': [{u'long_name': u'908', u'types': [u'street_number'], u'short_name': u'908'}, {u'long_name': u'Main Street', u'types': [u'route'], u'short_name': u'Main St'}, {u'long_name': u'Nutana', u'types': [u'neighborhood', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Nutana'}, {u'long_name': u'Saskatoon', u'types': [u'locality', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Saskatoon'}, {u'long_name': u'Division No. 11', u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_2', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Division No. 11'}, {u'long_name': u'Saskatchewan', u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_1', u'political'], u'short_name': u'SK'}, {u'long_name': u'Canada', u'types': [u'country', u'political'], u'short_name': u'CA'}, {u'long_name': u'S7H 0K5', u'types': [u'postal_code'], u'short_name': u'S7H 0K5'}], u'place_id': u'ChIJsxCU4S3xBFMROWgVYKfOkko', u'formatted_address': u'908 Main St, Saskatoon, SK S7H 0K5, Canada', u'types': [u'premise']}
```

I plan to filter different pieces of data and place them each to their own Pandas columns. For that, I created a for loop

```
tempCol = []

for dataPiece in location2:
    try:
        for item in dataPiece['address_components']:
            if item['types'] == ['locality', 'political']: 
                print item['long_name']
                tempCol.append(item['long_name'])


    except:
        print 'No data'
        tempCol.append('None')

Saskatoon
Little Fort
Clinton
Johnson Lake
Edinburgh
Clearwater
Karachi
Blind Bay
Clearwater
```

It outputs a list of cities, which are usually tagged as locality, political in Google Maps API. There is a mistake though because, for cells that do not have those tags, it's not returning anything, and therefore my location2 list of shorter than the length of the pandas column.

This is an example of a Google API result that is not yielding any response from the loop because it doesn't have a locality, political key:

```
{u'geometry': {u'location_type': u'GEOMETRIC_CENTER', u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': 55.9375528, u'lng': -3.1831058}, u'southwest': {u'lat': 55.93223440000001, u'lng': -3.1885178}}, u'viewport': {u'northeast': {u'lat': 55.9375528, u'lng': -3.1831058}, u'southwest': {u'lat': 55.93223440000001, u'lng': -3.1885178}}, u'location': {u'lat': 55.9347423, u'lng': -3.1867772}}, u'formatted_address': u'Lauder Rd, Edinburgh EH9, UK', u'place_id': u'ChIJJfqkc3nHh0gRF64Imw-sw-U', u'address_components': [{u'long_name': u'Lauder Road', u'types': [u'route'], u'short_name': u'Lauder Rd'}, {u'long_name': u'Edinburgh', u'types': [u'postal_town'], u'short_name': u'Edinburgh'}, {u'long_name': u'Edinburgh', u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_2', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Edinburgh'}, {u'long_name': u'Scotland', u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_1', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Scotland'}, {u'long_name': u'United Kingdom', u'types': [u'country', u'political'], u'short_name': u'GB'}, {u'long_name': u'EH9', u'types': [u'postal_code', u'postal_code_prefix'], u'short_name': u'EH9'}], u'partial_match': True, u'types': [u'route']}
```

In those instances, I would like the return to be a None, but I'm having issues because if add an else None statement, it returns None for each key in the dictionary.

Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I couldn't find any better way to parse through this dataframe, I realize that for loops are notoriously slow, if you can suggest a different tool to do the parsing let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: You've fallen in the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Try to describe what your actual problem is (which you've done already partly) and not why your solution is not working.

Comment: @Erfan I have edited the question, hope it explains the problem better now